# Plotting datetime from PyMongo -> Pandas in matplotlib

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

I'm attempting to put a MongoDB database that I've imported with PyMongo into a pandas dataframe and then plot it by time with a "date" column of type datetime64 with matplotlib. However, I'm getting randomly connected dates. Does anyone know how I might fix this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `date` column seems to be unsorted. To reproduce consider e.g.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(15,5), columns=list("ABCDE"))
a = np.arange("2018-05-05", "2018-05-20", dtype="datetime64[D]")
np.random.shuffle(a)
df["date"] = a

plt.plot("date", "C", data=df)
plt.show()
```

[image]

If we [sort the dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by the `date` column now,

```
df.sort_values(by="date", inplace=True)
```

the result looks much nicer.

[image]

---

A tangential remark here: I would recommend deciding for one style, either

```
plt.plot("date", "C", data=df)
```

or

```
plt.plot(df["date"], df["C"])
```

and not mix the two by supplying the x argument as Series and the y as string.